# Inserting "line break" inside block element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert what I assume to be a line break in a css block element. I've tried the simple `<br>` tag and tried adjusting a heading element (h3 e.g.) with margins, padding, etc to fit inside the block with no luck.

This is an example of what I wish to achieve https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xaKU.jpg and this is what I have so far. http://jsfiddle.net/3q7on4v2/ it's pretty close in my opinion, but not like I want it yet. any help is appreciated

`<div id="bg">
        <ul class="nav">
        <h1> Tonight </h1>
            <li><a href="#notisia">E Notisia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#wega">Mercee</a></li>
            <li><a href="#konkulshon">Last Call</a></li>
            <li><a href="cinema">Unu-Unu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>`

```
.nav {
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden; }

.nav a{
display: block;
width: 200px;
height:60px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #323643;
text-align: center;
line-height:60px;
padding: 4px;
text-decoration: none;
border-left: 1px solid #818181;}

.nav a:hover {background-color: #404452; }
.nav li{ float: right; }
h1 {
color: #F2F2F3;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding: 0; }
#bg { background-color: #323643; }
```

Comment: What is exactly the final result? Are you trying to place the header in the vertical middle of the cell?

Comment: You cannot use other elements than `li` directly in lists (`ul`, `ol`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the jsfiddle code. So have a look. You will see I added a span within the h1 tag and styled the span to be smaller font and you could do a different color what ever you want.

You might just need a wrapper around it at this point everything floats to the right.

```
<div id="bg">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#notisia">E Notisia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#wega">Mercee</a></li>
        <li><a href="#konkulshon">Last Call</a></li>
        <li><a href="cinema">Unu-Unu</a></li>
    </ul>
<h1>Tonight
    <span>test</span>
</h1>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

```css
ul{padding:0; margin:0;}
ul li{padding:0; margin:0;}

.nav {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-top: 0px;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
    float:right;
}

.nav a{
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 height:60px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #323643;
 text-align: center;
 line-height:60px;
 padding: 4px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-left: 1px solid #818181;
}
.nav a:hover {background-color: #404452; }
.nav li{
 float: right;
}
h1 {
 color: #F2F2F3;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px 10px;
    float:right;
    margin:0;
}
h1 span{ font-size:12px; display:block;}
.clear{ clear:both;}
#bg { background-color: #323643; margin:0; padding:0; }
```